# App merge release resources error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I get the following errors while trying to build a signatured APK:

[image]

[image]

I've looked through ThreadPoolExecutor.java and there are some errors but when I'm editing it, it says that it's not part of the project so I'm assuming it's part of the IDE? What could be the problem?

Here's my plugin.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.riddimdub.radio'
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
```

In the `android { }`